# What is a good StrongLoop/GitHub continuous integration pipeline?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, strongloop

What is a good workflow for developing sites with strongloop and github/bitbucket, for sending your project to testing and then production?

I see the individual ingredients for a really solid workflow, but am curious to see what has been done to stitch together a decent end-to-end continuous integration pipeline (or something close to it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is pretty generic, but I will try to answer parts of it.

Since as LoopBack is unopinionated and uses Express underneath the hood, you can use any workflow that would typically work for Express.

For VCS, GitHub and Bitbucket is good.

There are many Node.js specific providers (a Google search will provide many results).

As for testing, you can use something like Mocha + Chai and then have Travis or Codeship to run your tests. As for end-to-end, it would really depend on your front end technology stack too (ie. Angular/Karma, etc).

You should also take a look at http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Getting+started+with+LoopBack